# Why cursor begin with 0?

Tags: android, cursor

I have the **MainFragment:**

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    MissedCallCounter listener = new MissedCallCounter(getActivity());
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setCountCalls();
}

public void setCountCalls() {
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        ...
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public void setCountCalls() {
    mainFragment.setCountCalls();
}
```

and **MissedCallCounter:**

```
public class MissedCallCounter extends PhoneStateListener {
 private Context mContext;

 public MissedCallCounter(Context context) {
     mContext = context;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
     super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
     MainActivity mainFragment = (MainActivity) mContext;
     mainFragment.setCountCalls();
 }
}
```

**Question:** Why cursor begin with 0? If I get 1 missed call, that `cursor.getCount() = 0`, if I get 2 missed calls, that `cursor.getCount() = 1` etc. But if I reopen MainFragment, that 1 missed call == `cursor.getCount() = 1` etc, as it should be. But it work only if I again reopen MainFragment. WHY? How fix it?

Comment: Try moving your `super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);` at last.

Comment: Have you tried calling `setCountCalls` by directly creating instance of `MainFragment`?

Comment: yes. problem is not instance fragment or calling method. problem is cursor return count-1

Comment: Yah I got that, But the problem may be this method may be called count times lesser than `onCallStateChanged` called.

Comment: mmm.. ok. but nothing doesn't work